# SSIS: Why does sequence container require TransactionOption Required in order to report task failure?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a job that creates files on the network folder from various non-database sources. Within the job, I isolate the various file creation tasks (contained in a sequence container) from the move file task (foreach enumerator) in order to prevent a spiders web of precedence constraints from the various file creation tasks:

1. Data flow task that contains script component using C# and LDAP to pull data from Active Directory and output it to multiple files
2. Script Component that downloads files from SFTP (implements WinSCPNET.dll)

Upon successful completion, the sequence container then goes to a foreach file enumerator to move the extracted files to a folder that indicates files are ready for loading - there is no problem here.

However, an intermittent problem arose in production where the AD connection was terminating before the file extract process completed, resulting in partial files (this was not observed in testing, but should have been contemplated - my bad). So, I added a foreach enumerator outside of the sequence container with a failure precedence constraint to delete these partial extract files.

During testing of this fix, I set one of the tasks within the sequence container to report failure. Initially, the sequence container reported success, thus bypassing the delete foreach enumerator. I tried setting the MaximumErrorCount from 0 to 1, but that did not result in the desired behavior change. I then changed the sequence container's TransactionOption from **supported** to **required** and this appears to have fixed the problem. Now, the job moves files that are completely extracted while deleting files that report and error on extraction.

My question is this: Is there a potential problem going this route? I am unsure as to why this solution works. The documentation online discusses the TransactionOption in the context of a connection to the database. But, in this case there is no connection to the database. I just don't want to release a patch that may have a potential bug that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding Transactions and Files.
Presume you write your files to disk with an NTFS or another file system supporting transactions. Then all file create and file save actions are enclosed into one transaction. Had the transaction failed due to task failure, all the files created inside the transaction will be rolled back, i.e. deleted.
So, you will have an *"all or nothing"* approach on files, receiving files only if all extractions worked out.
In case you store the files on non-transactional file system, like old FAT, this *"all or nothing"* will no longer work and you will receive partial set of files. Transaction set on Sequence will have no such effect.

Comment: That makes sense - it would be helpful if Microsoft expanded their documentation to cover this point. But, I digress. Anyways, I went ahead and disabled the delete foreach enumerator and found that the files are not deleted when the task reports failure. So, I still need this step. But, it is good to understand why this solution works. Thank you.